# GLSL Depth Testing Information

Tags: java, glsl, shader, lwjgl, fragment-shader

I am currently programming some “Hacker glasses” for my game. They enable you to see through walls. I solved this by rendering every enemy into a framebuffer and then using a shader on that framebuffer. The frame buffer gets drawn as a 2D overlay afterwards. So currently I can display (and recolour) my enemies through walls. But how can I only Color the parts hidden behind a wall? I am just rendering a couple of 3D Object on top of each other in that scene with GL_DEPTH_TEST enabled.

If you need any code just let me know, I’ll post it below the question.

Comment: *"how can I only Color the parts hidden behind a wall"* - that's a bit unclear.  Do you mean that if half of an enemy is covered by a wall, then this half should be "colored"? If yes, t hen switch the depth test function to [`glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthFunc.xhtml) (for the "color enemy" post process)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, this is exactly what I mean. The problem is, I only render the enemies into that framebuffer and not the wall. Maybe I am wrong right here, but switching the depth test function wouldn’t have any effect on my enemies. Or didn’t I understand that?

Comment: Do you render the framebuffer in the default frambuffer? If yes, then this is the part where the depth test has to be switched to `GL_GREATER`. If no, then you've to use [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) (mask = `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT `) to copy the depth buffer to the frambuffer (of course the frambuffer has to have a depth buffer).